# Python error install nltk Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, pip, nltk

i'm trying to install nltk

**pip install nltk**

or

**pip3 install nltk**

but i have errors **Command errored out with exit status 1** and **Py_UCS1** errors:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/berendakova/PycharmProjects/search_info/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qg/8463dw456dl28nrzkknf4lqw0000gp/T/pip-install-U4OtRD/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qg/8463dw456dl28nrzkknf4lqw0000gp/T/pip-install-U4OtRD/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qg/8463dw456dl28nrzkknf4lqw0000gp/T/pip-record-ne7kCE/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/berendakova/PycharmProjects/search_info/venv/include/site/python2.7/regex
         cwd: /private/var/folders/qg/8463dw456dl28nrzkknf4lqw0000gp/T/pip-install-U4OtRD/regex/
    Complete output (87 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/regex
    copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/regex
    copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/regex
    copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/regex
    copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/regex
    running build_ext
    building 'regex._regex' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/regex_3
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/Users/berendakova/PycharmProjects/search_info/venv/include/python2.7 -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/regex_3/_regex.o
    regex_3/_regex.c:755:23: error: expected expression
        return *((Py_UCS1*)text + pos);
                          ^
   //MANY ERRORS WITH Py_UCS1
               
    regex_3/_regex.c:2103:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyExc_TimeoutError'; did you mean 'PyExc_ImportError'?
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TimeoutError, "regex timed out");
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            PyExc_ImportError
    /Users/berendakova/PycharmProjects/search_info/venv/include/python2.7/pyerrors.h:134:24: note: 'PyExc_ImportError' declared here
    PyAPI_DATA(PyObject *) PyExc_ImportError;
                           ^
    regex_3/_regex.c:3468:9: error: unknown type name 'Py_UCS1'; did you mean 'Py_UCS4'?
            Py_UCS1* text_ptr;
            ^~~~~~~
            Py_UCS4
    /Users/berendakova/PycharmProjects/search_info/venv/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:128:22: note: 'Py_UCS4' declared here
    typedef unsigned int Py_UCS4;
                         ^
    regex_3/_regex.c:3469:9: error: unknown type name 'Py_UCS1'; did you mean 'Py_UCS4'?
            Py_UCS1* limit_ptr;
            ^~~~~~~
            Py_UCS4
    /Users/berendakova/PycharmProjects/search_info/venv/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:128:22: note: 'Py_UCS4' declared here
    typedef unsigned int Py_UCS4;
                         ^
    regex_3/_regex.c:3471:29: error: expected expression
            text_ptr = (Py_UCS1*)text + text_pos;
                                ^
    regex_3/_regex.c:3471:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Py_UCS1'
            text_ptr = (Py_UCS1*)text + text_pos;
                        ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

i'm trying upgrade pip and trying use pip3, this is don't help me

i hope you can help me, thanks :)

Comment: The last version of `regex` compatible with Python 2.7 is [2021.3.17](https://pypi.org/project/regex/2021.3.17/). Install it with `pip install regex==2021.3.17`